# Array length declaration using variable

Tags: java

I'm trying to create an array named `positiveNumbersArray` with the length of the variable `positiveNumbers` and then store the positive numbers from the `array` in it. I'm getting this error:

> ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5

```
int positiveNumbers=0;

int[] array = {12, 0, -22, 0, 43, 545, -4, -55, 12, 43, 0, -999, -87};

for(int i = 0; i<array.length;i++)
    if (array[i] > 0) 
        positiveNumbers++;

int[] positiveNumbersArray = new int[positiveNumbers];

for(int i =0; i<array.length;i++){
    if (array[i] > 0)
        positiveNumbersArray[i]=array[i];
}
```

Comment: Did you make any attempt to investigate the cause?  Adding `System.out.println(i);` to your second loop would have answered your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you need a separate index for `positiveNumbersArray`. The simplest fix is:

```
positiveNumbers = 0;
for(int i =0; i<array.length;i++) {
    if(array[i] > 0)
       positiveNumbersArray[positiveNumbers++]=array[i];
}
```

This will insert the numbers into their correct positions in the `positiveNumbersArray`.

Comment: i did System.out.println(i) but i could not figure out what was wrong, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The size of array "array" more then "positiveNumbersArray" and you use index of array "array" to access in array "positiveNumbersArray".
For example: size of "array" is 15 and positive values count are 6. What
happens if index of positive value in array "array" are 8?

Try it:

```
    int positiveNumbers = 0;

    int[] array = {12, 0, -22, 0, 43, 545, -4, -55, 12, 43, 0, -999, -87};

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] > 0)
            positiveNumbers++;
    }

    int[] positiveNumbersArray = new int[positiveNumbers];

    for (int i = 0, index = 0; i < positiveNumbersArray.length; i++, index++) {

        while (array[index] <= 0) {
            index++;
        }
        positiveNumbersArray[i] = array[index];
    }
```